# Azure DevOps - Deploy Magento 2 - Request Entity too large code 413

Tags: php, azure, magento, azure-devops

I am trying to deploy Magento 2 sample code using Azure DevOps as part of CI/CD. I have build pipeline configured with YAML that takes up code from main branch and send to destination as zip.

The archive stage job is completed and the artifact is build with 2GB zip file. However, it fails in Deploy stage throwing error as below

```
Error - Failed to deploy web package to app service. Request entity too large code 413
```

Since the zip folder is 2GB, I have tried increasing value of `upload_max_filesize = 3G` in both `php.ini` and `.htaccess` files in Magento codebase

My current azure subscription allows only 1GB and when I downloaded main branch repo, the git folder itself has 1GB size.

- Is it possible to only push code to build pipeline minus the **.git** folder?

As I am new to CI/CD for Magento, any suggestions or changes in approach are welcome

Comment: Hi @Slimshadddyyy, how are things going? Have you tried the suggestion in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please have a try with it, and any progress, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am working on the YAML file to deploy Magento 2 on Azure but it is not working. Could you share some working YAML that would be helpful?

Comment: Hi @Slimshadddyyy, I have updated my answer to share a simple YMAL example. Please check it. Any questions about this, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Thanks @BrightRan-MSFT. I will check and let you know.

Comment: Okay, @Slimshadddyyy. any progress, feel free to tell me.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy Could you share some working YAML that would be helpful? I am working on the YAML file to deploy Magento 2 on Azure but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the zip folder is 2GB, I have tried increasing value of upload_max_filesize = 3G in both php.ini and .htaccess files in Magento codebase

When deploying app to Azure App Service with a ZIP or WAR file, the file size limit of **`2048 MB`** (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip)).

> Is it possible to only push code to build pipeline minus the .git folder?

Before archiving the artifact, you can exclude the **`.git`** folder. In your pipeline, generally you can do like as this:

1. Use the [**Copy Files task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy the files you require to a target folder via the [file matching patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops) you set in the '**`Contents`**' field.

   - use the positive patterns to only include the files you require.
   - use the negative patterns (start with '**`!`**') to exclude the files you do not require. In your case, you can try this pattern (`!.git/**`).
2. Use the [**Archive Files task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops) to archive the files as a ZIP file from the target folder.
3. Deploy the ZIP file.

**[UPDATE]**

Please reference to this example to update your YAML pipeline:

```yaml
steps:
--- some other tasks such as build, test ---
  . . .
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'path/to/Source/Folder'
    Contents: '!.git/**'  # Exclude the '.git' folder
    TargetFolder: 'path/to/Target/Folder'
    CleanTargetFolder: true
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'path/to/root/Folder'  # This path is same as the 'TargetFolder' in the CopyFiles task
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: 'path/to/ZIP/file'  # This is the path to generate the ZIP file, e.g. "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip"
    replaceExistingArchive: true

--- task to deploy the ZIP file to Azure ---
```

Comment: It says 
##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
##[error]Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed.

Comment: hello can you share  the YAML file to deploy Magento 2 on Azure please .